# Could someone explain this code for me? window.clientTimeDivergence = (1366265216 * 1000) - (new Date).getTime();

Tags: javascript

> window.clientTimeDivergence = (1366265216 * 1000) - (new
>   Date).getTime();

I want to know what the changing value 1366265216 means; and what this whole expression means.

Thanks all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`(new Date()).getTime()` gives the present time in `milliseconds`, so `1366265216` appears to be some time in **seconds** which is being converted to `milliseconds`  so as to subtract the resultant from `(new Date()).getTime()`.

By the way, u are missing the `()` in the `(new Date).getDate();`

Plus, u can check `var date = new Date(1366265216)` or `var date = new Date(1366265216*1000)` to find out the date/time out of the `1366265216`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! Practically, `(new Date).getDate()` also works well, maybe function is also object in javascript?

Comment: never checked that..thanks for pointing out! :)

Answer (score 3):

In the expression:

```
1366265216
```

Is probably a UNIX time value that is seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z and is probably 2013-04-18T06:06:56Z. Just do:

```
alert(new Date(1366265216*1000));
```

to see what it is for your local timezone.

Javascript date objects have a [time value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) that uses the same epoch, but in milliseconds. Hence the value is multiplied by 1,000 to change it to milliseconds.

```
new Date
```

returns a javascript Date object for the current time.

```
.getTime();
```

returns the time value of the javascript date object (i.e. milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). So the result is the difference in milliseconds between the two times.

It's probably being used to estimate the time it takes to send data from the server to the client, and assumes that the clocks at both ends are synchronised (or at least synchronised within an acceptable tolerance of perhaps few seconds). That is is likely if both are connected to the internet and configured correctly, however there is no guarantee that they are.

Comment: Then I run the code:  
window.clientTimeDivergence = (1366265216 * 1000) - (new Date).getTime();
and I got this answer: -2226910(keeping changing with time)
what this result represent and what can this result do in web apps?
I am confused about this...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the real-world meaning of the code! Exactly that way!

Answer (score 1):

Grooveshark front-end engineer here. Looks like you found this from our source code.

The code is getting the difference of the server time and the user's time, which is then used for all time calculations for the site. This helps us later when we need a time value to be shown in the user's time zone or relative to the user's clock.

It could've been used to determine how long the request took, but RobG pointed out, the user's clock could be wrong. The value is calculated at the end of the response so our offset could be slightly wrong if the response took a while to reach the user's browser but that difference rarely matters.